# Assign keys and values from [(key: String, value: [[String : Any]])] in UITableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries, `[[String:AnyObject]]`, which is reduce+sorted as below successfully.

```
 var arrUserList = [(key: String, value: [[String : Any]])]()


 let result = self.arrJsonDict.reduce(into: [String: [[String:Any]]]()) { result, element in
                    let strName: String = (element as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "name") as! String
                    if let firstLetter = strName.first {
                        let initial = String(describing: firstLetter).uppercased()
                        result[initial, default: [[String:Any]]() ].append(element as! [String : Any])
                    }}.sorted { return $0.key < $1.key }


     self.arrUserList = result
```

Now I wanted to assign keys to table sections and values as table cell text from the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very cumbersome code.

You are highly encouraged to use a struct rather than a dictionary at least with a member `name`

```
struct Person {
    let name : String
}
```

---

Declare and rename `arrJsonDic` (more descriptively) as

```
var people : [Person]()
```

and `arrUserList` as

```
var users = [String: [Person]]()
```

For the sections declare another array

```
var letters = [String]()
```

---

Group the array and populate `letters` simply with

```
users = Dictionary(grouping: people, by: { String($0.name.first!) })
letters = users.keys.sorted()
```

---

In the table view in `numberOfSections` return

```
return letters.count
```

and in `numberOfRows` return

```
let letter = letters[section]
return users[letter]!.count
```

In `cellForRowAt` assign a name to a label with

```
let letter = letters[indexPath.section]
let user = users[letter]![indexPath.row]
cell.nameLabel.text = user.name
```

### ------------------------------

To make it still *swiftier* declare a second struct `Section`

```
struct Section {
    let index : String
    let people : [Person]
}
```

delete

<strike>`var letters = [String]()`</strike>

and declare `users`

```
var users = [Section]()
```

The grouping is slightly different

```
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: people, by: { String($0.name.first!) })
users = grouped.map({ Section(index: $0.0, people: $0.1) }).sorted{$0.index < $1.index}
```

The code in the three table view delegate methods are

```
return users.count
```

-

```
return users[section].people.count
```

-

```
let user = users[indexPath.section].people[indexPath.row]
cell.nameLabel.text = user.name
```

Comment: Thanks @vadian, but i am getting an error "Cannot assign value of type 'Dictionary<String, [Person]>' to type '[String : Person]' ", while grouping the Dictionary.

Comment: My bad, it must be `var users = [String: [Person]]()`. Answer updated.

Comment: Using this code tableView returns me only first index of section with single record